# Failure to create a mesh with ToElementMesh

Tags: finite-element-method

When I created mesh by function with `ToElementMesh`, some errors occured. The code below is a minimal example. I can't understand why it failed.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
coordinates = {{0,0}, {1,0}, {1,1}, {0,1}};
meshinc = TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 4}}];
mesh = ToElementMesh["Coordinates" -> coordinates, "MeshElements" -> {meshinc}]
```

I think it should have succeeded in creating a triangle element with the vertexs of $(0,0)$, $(1,0)$, $(0,1)$, I know the nodes of the elements should be in the anticlockwise dieection, but it stilled failed. However, it will succeed when

```
meshinc = TriangleElement[{{1, 2, 3}}]
```

The code below also failed

```
mesh = 
 ToElementMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> 
     {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 0}, {0, 1}, {1, 1}, {2, 1}, {0, 2}, {1, 2}, {2, 2}}, 
  "MeshElements" -> {QuadElement[{{1, 2, 5, 4}}]}]
```

Could you explain my failures and advise me on some principles to use when creating a mesh?

Comment: The reason is given in the error message. See my answer/long comment.

Answer (score 4):

The explanation is in the error message (emphasis mine):

> ToElementMesh::fememins: The mesh elements are not valid. A set of valid mesh element incidents needs to be positive integers and be able to form a **complete sequence starting from 1 to the largest incident present.** There are missing incidents; a complete sequence cannot be formed. >>

It helps to give complete information in the question, by the way, including error messages.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Michael E2,  I'm using a Chinese version MMA, I think maybe I can switch to English :)

Comment: Oh I noted the message provided in Chinese, it looks so strange

Comment: @Ice0cean Ah.  Do you mean the messages say something different in Chinese?

Comment: Yes, even I'm a native Chinese speaker, I can't understand what's the message means, it looks confusing. em, just like some Chinese characters's combination  :( Maybe something wrong when translated to Chinese.

Comment: @Ice0cean Yes, it must take a lot of work to get all the translations correct.  Consider reporting it to WRI, if you can.

Comment: @Ice0cean, there will be a new version of Chinese message and hopefully that is better understandable. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @user21 Thanks :)